# How to run JUnit tests on Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1?

Tags: android, android-studio, junit

I have run configuration at `.idea/workspace.xml`:

```
<configuration name="appTests" type="AndroidJUnit" factoryName="Android JUnit">
      <module name="myproject-android.app" />
      <option name="PACKAGE_NAME" value="" />
      <option name="MAIN_CLASS_NAME" value="" />
      <option name="METHOD_NAME" value="" />
      <option name="TEST_OBJECT" value="package" />
      <option name="PARAMETERS" value="" />
      <option name="WORKING_DIRECTORY" value="$MODULE_DIR$" />
      <method v="2">
        <option name="Android.Gradle.BeforeRunTask" enabled="true" />
      </method>
    </configuration>
```

But I can't run it on new version of Android Studio due to error:

```
Run Configuration Error:  Android JUnit test configurations are no longer supported: You should instead use the Gradle run configuration for your unit tests. You can find your existing configurations at <my-app>/.idea/workspace.xml.
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run directly by using gradlew ..  ./gradlew clean allTests

Comment: Task 'allTests' not found in root project

Comment: to display all gradle tasks you can check File -> Settings -> Experimental -> Do not build Gradle task list during Gradle sync  then you need to synch your project by File -> sync project with gradle files.